# Confusion with Bode plot in LTspice when using a voltage regulator

Tags: ltspice, bode-plot

To experiment(out of curiosity) the effect of a low pass filter for an SMPS switching noise I wanted to try a filter where an LC cascaded by a linear regulator as shown in below diagram, I obtained the AC analysis in LTspice.

[image]

I don't know anything about the output impedance of the SMPS so I chose is as 1 Ohm. Then I swept the input between 0.1Hz to 1 Meg Hz.

But why in the Bode plot Vout starts from -180dB but not 0dB?

---

**EDIT:**

Following some comments I superimposed the noise on a 24V DC as shown below:

[image]

The AC coupling caps C4 and C3 are there to view the noise component at the input and output.

Here is when 1V 100 kHz **square wave** noise(with 1p rising and falling edges) is superimposed on the 24V DC:

[image]

Here is when 1V 100 kHz **sine wave** noise is superimposed on the 24V DC:

[image]

Below is when 1V **0.1 Hz** **sine wave** noise is superimposed on the 24V DC:

[image]

And finally here is the AC response when superimposed on the 24V DC:

[image]

It seems in the AC response at 0.1 Hz the y axis shows around -70dB. This corresponds to a voltage ratio of 3162 and for 1V the output would be expected as 320uV which almost matches to the 0.1 Hz transient response noise amplitude.

Are these results expected in practice? If so it seems to me the linear regulator works as a very very strong low pass filter.

Comment: 0dB is unity gain; -180dB is a gain of \$\small 10^{-9}\$. Why is -180dB surprising? The idea of a regulator is to give pure direct voltage, or as close as possible. This one is pretty good at it.

Comment: I interpret the dB vertical axis of the plot mathematically as 20*log10(Vout/Vin) verus the frequency axis. If not what is it?

Comment: At 0 or 0.1Hz the regulator should not attenuate anything but it does. Very confusing to me.

Comment: Yes that's correct for your first comment;volt/volt = gain . How have you checked it at 0 Hz? that frequency isn't on the Bode plot, also, the supply voltage must be greater than the intended output regulated voltage otherwise the regulator can't work.

Comment: @Chu I will try to elaborate on my confusion very soon hope you can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Where did you fond that model for `LM340` in LTspice? There is no such model on their site, either. Did you just use the Linear logo because it "looks cool"? Don't do that, it confuses only. Can you post the contents of your model? I have a feeling it's not a model that allows `.AC` analysis, only `.TRAN`.

Comment: @user164567 I think you are looking at the output response relative to changes in the input. A good regulator will maintain the output despite changes in the input (source) voltage. If I follow things here, all you are seeing is that this is a pretty good regulator with respect to input voltage changes -- the output "barely" sees these changes. You definitely would not want to see 0dB for this!!

Comment: Hi all due to illness I could just update the question; please see my edit. I made the input source DC plus AC(noise) now and presented the sim results. Even at 0.1Hz the noise is attenuated 70dB. Does that mean using such regulator really creates a strong LP filter? If so, is this used in practice?

Comment: @jonk You wrote "A good regulator will maintain the output despite changes in the input". Does that mean the voltage regulator can be used as a LP differential filter? Is it used in practice for that purpose?

Comment: A LP filter should have unity gain at dc but a voltage regulator **does not**. Do not think of a voltage regulator as a filter.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the reference level for LTspice ac plots is that 0 dB = 1 V. So, it looks like your ac signal is very, very small. Keep in mind that this is a simulation, not real life, so there are round-off errors that can accumulate and look like very small noise signals.

EDIT: Your simulation provides an **input** voltage of 1V for the regulator. An LM340T-12 is not going to function properly with that small of an input voltage, you need **at least** 14V to make this device work. I think your simulation results are probably bogus.

Comment: At 0Hz OR 0.1Hz the regulator will pass 1V DC input as 1V DC output which is 0 dB, but in the plot at 0.1 Hz the output is -180dB. Can that be because I need to bias this regulator?

Comment: What makes you think that there is an ac component of 1V at 0.1 Hz? You are saying that over the course of ten seconds the output voltage changes from 0 to 2V and back again. When you perform an ac simulation there is no dc component in the results.

Comment: What I want to see is the "regulator filter"'s effect to the SMPS switching noise superimposed on the DC output of the SMPS. Either it is really filtering 180dB at 0.1Hz or my sim is wrong.

Comment: Then you want a transient simulation, not an ac frequency sweep.

Comment: The input source must be dc and ac: the dc fixes the operating point, for instance 15 V and then you add a 1-V ac modulation. Please make sure the operating point is correct, e.g. \$V_{out}\$ delivers the correct value before considering the results. I know LTspice can reflect the OP back to the schematic. It must always be done before considering any ac results.

Comment: Make sure you have a working DC simulation before running an AC sim.  This would catch things like the improper DC bias of the regulator input mentioned above.  When your DC simulation shows the correct DC results, then run the AC sim.

Comment: Due to illness I could just update the question; please see my edit. I made the input source dc plus ac(noise) now and presented the sim results. Even at 0.1Hz the noise is attenuated 70dB. Does that mean using such regulator really creates a strong LP filter? If so, is this used in practice?

Comment: It's not thought of as a low-pass filter. The term that is usually used is **ripple regulation**, which specifies how much the ac ripple in the input voltage will be attenuated. TI specifies a typical value of 72dB at 120Hz. At very low frequencies you should consider **load regulation**, and TI says a maximum change of 120mV for a change of input from 15V to 27V. **However**, your simulation model likely models typical behavior rather than worst-case.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson One of my ignorance for these type of simulations is what to put as a source impedance, in this case as you see I added a Rs =  1 Ohm series resistance to mimic the SMPS output impedance. This resistance in many cases dramatically changes the sim results. Do you recommend to measure it empirically or is there rule of thumb for the output impedance for an SMPS? Thank you.

Comment: No, there is no rule of thumb. You get this from the specifications for the SMPS. You might be able to infer it from the line regulation spec.